# How to find Test Sets without any tests in them?

Tags: jira, jql, jira-xray

I am trying to create a search that will return all the Test Sets that are empty (without any assigned Tests in them).

I've checked the testSetTests function, but I can't find a way of checking that the number of those tests is zero.

Did anyone face this problem? any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I have the same challange. The only option I have found so far is to get in the reslut list view the extra column "Test Set Status". It shows the status and informs you about no test.


But, from the [documentation:](https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/Enhanced+querying+with+JQL)


>The Test Set Status and Test Plan Status custom fields, mentioned in Custom Fields, >are not queryable. 


hope it gets you a tiny step forward.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution which works for me:

`project = PROJEKTNAME AND type = "Test Set" AND "Test Count" = 0`

It is more an indirect search but if "Test Count" is Empty there will be no Tests releated to a TestSet